# Does tf.data.Dataset.from_generator cache generated data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset, generator

My question is, does the `dataset` created with the [`from_generator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) function cache the generated data after the first epoch? If it pulls data from the generator after each epoch, is there a way to cache data to speed up model training?
I work with different shape arrays (RaggedTensor) and it looks like the generator is a way to go in this case.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#cache